# Typescript error: This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof import("koa-session")' has no call signatures

Tags: node.js, typescript

**Partially solved:**

**There is an old issue on github where this problem is described a bit. When you declare a module in a global scope, it rewrites the whole exported module's types. When you declare a module inside a module, it merges. Why? I have no idea**

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17736#issuecomment-344353174

I want to extend third party module's type by interface merging. Everything works fine, but when I comment 
`export {};` in **types.d.ts** I encounter the following error:

> This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof import("koa-session")'
>   has no call signatures

Could you explain why it happens?

You can check the working code here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-node-nocfq?file=/src/types.d.ts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A similar problem has been addressed on [TypeScript github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17736#issuecomment-323073256). Unfortunately I am now aware of any other documentation page that would describe it.

Commenting out the `export {}` turns the `types.d.ts` file from a *module* into a *script*. From [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#introduction):

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

Since the file without export statement (and without import statement) is not a module but rather a script it has no information about any modules and will indeed disregard the fact that there is an existing definition for "koa-session".

You can try this in your sandbox - adding any top-level `import` or `export` in `types.d.ts` (it can be completely unused) will fix the `This expression is not callable` error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't describe my problem. I use declare module "koa-session" which, logically, should work the same
in modules and in a global scope. But it behaves differently. I already figured out, that using module "koa-session" in a global scope rewrites any module's exported types. Why? I have no idea, it's not described anywhere

Comment: Since the file without export statement (and without import statement) is not a module but rather a script it has no information about any modules and will indeed disregard the fact that there is an existing definition for "koa-session". There is no documentation i know of apart from this github thread (sorry there is a lot going on there, pick the bits that are relevant) https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17736#issuecomment-344353174

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems to be what I expected. It even explains why a namespace should be omitted. Could you append this link and format your question accordingly to it? I will accept it and reward you the bounty

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the interface if you want to enhance it and do interface merging. What you're doing is rewriting it altogether.

```
import Session from "koa-session";
declare module "koa-session" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: number;
      username: string;
    };
  }
}
```

Just do this and you will enhance the interface just as you want.

Comment: According to the docs, I can't rewrite it because of declaration merging. Also when I add just "export {}" it merges correctly. I assume the same happens when you import anything, not only session

Comment: Could give a link to the docs where it says that Typescript allows to rewrite instead of merging?

Comment: Also I don't need a solution. I need an explanation